# Error updating BIT field in SQL database (using PHP PDO driver)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bit

I have the following code:

```
$SQL = "UPDATE jobs
        SET read = '1'
        WHERE id = '$job_id'";

$STH = $DBH->prepare($SQL);
$STH->execute();
```

`read` is a field in the table with a data type of `BIT`. The current data inside this field is `0` (false), and I'm trying to change it to `1` (true). However, I am getting this error:

> Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read = '1' WHERE id = '25'' at line 2

I can't see any syntax errors, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`READ` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL.

You will need to quote it in order to use it as column name:

```
$SQL = "UPDATE jobs
        SET `read` = '1'
        WHERE id = '$job_id'";
```

This is why a quote everything in every query, to avoid problems like this. Remember, quoting object names (tables, columns etc) must be done with *backticks*: `` ` ``